# Criar JSON em um arquivo txt

Tags: php, json

Como faço pra transformar um arquivo.txt em json ?

```
$linhas = fopen ("sections.txt", "r");      


        //percorre                                 
       while (!feof ($linhas)){

         $ponteiro = fgets($linhas, 1096);
            $valores = preg_split("[/]",$ponteiro);

           $paraTxt = $valores[0];

           //não pega o ; inicial do arquivo
           $paraTxt = substr ($valores[0],1);// aqui
           // echo '<br>'. $paraTxt;


           //novo array php
           $arrSection[] = array($paraTxt);                   
             $paraJson = json_encode($arrSection);          

         }
        // $paraJson = json_encode($arrSection);

         var_dump($paraJson); 
         //fclose ($linhas); */



do jeito que fiz retornando false.
```

> leitor.php:238:boolean false

Alguma dica de transformar este arquivo,onde ele já ler e percorre  no formato txt, e quando uso a function para transformar em json me retorna false
 Que no final quero chamar este array no javascript,ser listado no typehead.

Comment: Quando vc da echo em `$paraTxt` aparece algo? o `json_encode()` deveria estar fora do while. Pode simplificar `$arrSection[] = array($paraTxt);`  por `$arrSection[] = $paraTxt;` aí  o array gerado fica com apenas uma dimensão.

Comment: Sim ,aparece o conteúdo do arquivo txt,ou seja ele ler... antes do json_encode , quando uso a função me retorna false